# Connecting two USB 2.0 devices to a single USB port on an MCU

Tags: usb, layout, signal-integrity, routing

I'm designing a PCB where I need to have two possible USB 2.0 connectors (and hence 2 sets of diff pairs) connect to a single USB 2.0 port on an MCU. Only a single connector would be used at any given time. What can I do to improve the signal quality? I've heard of redrivers/retimers but can these be used in this scenario to get around the effects of reflections due to the stub I would be introducing? If so, how many would I need and where would I add them?
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would always be implemented using a switch IC rather than just a junction; with that, there'd be no stub line, no need for redriving.

Many silicon manufacturers do offer such ICs, many even explicitly specified for USB2 signaling. Check e.g. TI.com's [selection of USB 2.0 switches](http://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/protocol-specific/products.html#p1389=USB%202.0). Or [Maxim's](https://para.maximintegrated.com/search.mvp?fam=swmux_low&270=USB%20Certified&tree=master). Or [NXP's](https://www.nxp.com/products/analog/interfaces/usb-interfaces/usb-type-c-true-plugn-play/high-speed-signal-switches:HS-SIGNAL-SWITCHES). Or  [ON Semi's](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/parametrics.do?id=963) (show "ALL" instead of 50, search for USB). Or [Analog Device's](http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/10624#/d=sel|0|s6|s8|4683|4811|4814|4812|4813|546|4264|4270|2606|4458|s3|s5&ps6=usb). Or [intersil's](https://www.intersil.com/en/parametricsearch.html?g=switches-muxs-crosspoints&sg=usb-switches#g=switches-muxs-crosspoints&sg=usb-switches&f=usb-high-full-speed-switches-muxs) (now Renesas). Or [ROHM's](http://www.rohm.com/web/global/search/parametric/-/search/USB%20Switch%20ICs).

Comment: It is not "probably be made easy", it is a MUST to use either electronics switch, or electromechanical (RF-grade relay) switch to accomplish the task. It is plain impossible to fork high-speed communication wires without introducing horrible reflections and demolishing all signal integrity.

Comment: @AliChen Better, now?

Comment: @AliChen by the way, what you said about impossibility of high-speed comm lines isn't strictly true; for unidirectional wires, a simple matched 3dB split would do, for bidirectional you'd need something isolated (like a Wilkinson divider). Problem with those is that it's hard to make them work matchedly over a large bandwidth (large relative to the center frequency). And since USB isn't exactly "spectrally nice" in that aspect (or generally, tbh), you're right, *practically feasible* is only switching. (also, it avoids the at least 3dB of power loss.)

Comment: Yes, this is better. 3dB loss will surely kill all USB signal template (eye diagram) requirements. Also, since the USB 2.0 is bi-directional, "re-drivers" are notoriously difficult to implement and do not exist. Instead, USB hubs with "repeater path" are used. Also, a fork will create logical difficulties for USB protocol if both devices are attached.

Comment: @AliChen I'm pretty sure [TUSB214](http://www.ti.com/product/tusb214) does exist :) but, yeah, detecting the direction is probably a hard thing to do, which is why they're not telling much about how they do it in the Data sheet.

Comment: Yep, now I recall this crazy device from TI. It is supposed to sit on the TOP of diff trace pair WITHOUT CUT. I don 't understand how it could be working with a short between ports; maybe someone can explain it.

Comment: This would be my very incompetent guessing, and seeing that I'm already in bed, I think that this would be a nice pro-level question you could ask on here separately, but: high-input-impedance bandpass filter to detect edges, driving a push/pull cmos element. And some compensation that inhibits effect of that same element on the observation.

Comment: Ok, I posted my first question ever on EE, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/351917/117785.